# How to deal with many views in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have one ViewController that holds a main View. This main View holds other two views called leftView and rightView.

I would like to have these "auxiliary" views to be hidden upon app launch and I thought that the best way to do this would be offsetting X axis.

I want to do this offsetting via code to have all organised, but it's not working - it only works if I do it in the Interface Builder!

I tried two things and both did not work.

1: Via AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    O_GViewController *mainController = (O_GViewController *)  self.window.rootViewController;
    [mainController leftView].frame = CGRectMake(-211, 20, 211, 548);
    [mainController rightView].frame = CGRectMake(320, 20, 320, 548);

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

2: Via ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //initialize secondary views
    leftView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-211, 20, 211, 548)];
    rightView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 20, 320, 548)];
}
```

Both "auxiliary" views are bind with *leftView and *rightView in ViewController.h.

Would you have any idea of how to make this work via code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The *easiest* way to have the two views be hidden on launch is to set their `hidden` properties to YES. You can do that in Interface Builder.

If you really want the views positioned offscreen, you can of course do that. But then if you are using auto layout (which you almost certain are) you can't do it by setting their frames, because auto layout will just set their frames right back again in accordance with the constraints. You have to do it by manipulating constraints.

Comment: And in fact I have an example of that sort of constraint manipulation here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p255rotationChangesInterface/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.m It happens in response to rotation but that's not essential; the point is that it shows you how to swap constraints in and out in order to alter the interface in a way that is consistent with auto layout.